# error Call to a member function get_results()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hook

error:

> Call to a member function
>   get_results() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\viwe.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\viwe.php on line

the code

```
global $wpdb;

$query = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM test');
```

The folder myplugin contains the following two files,

```
index.php

viwe.php
```

For file viwe.php, the code is not working and fails with,

> error
>   Call to a member function
>   get_results() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\viwe.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\viwe.php on line

But the index.php is working.

Comment: Add these two lines at the top. `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  $folder . '/wp-load.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines at the top.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-load.php');
```

You need to include those files so the function `get_results()` becomes available to be called.